# Difficulty in sending location of user 1 to user 2 and user 2's location to user 1?

Tags: java, android, gps, sms, location

I have a code which sends location of user 1 to  user 2 and user 2's location to user 1 . The location of user 1 is send perfectly to user 2 and user 2 is even sending a message back to user 1 but the location which it is sending is the location of user 1 not his (user 2) location.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.gui;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ReceivelocationActivity extends BroadcastReceiver  {

    private static final String TAG = "LocationActivity";
    public static final String SMS_URI = "content://sms";
    public static final String ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String PERSON = "person";
    public static final String DATE = "date";
    public static final String READ = "read";
    public static final String STATUS = "status";
    public static final String TYPE = "type";
    public static final String BODY = "body";
    public static final String SEEN = "seen";


    public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX = 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT = 2;

    public static final int MESSAGE_IS_NOT_READ = 0;
    public static final int MESSAGE_IS_READ = 1;

    public static final int MESSAGE_IS_NOT_SEEN = 0;
    public static final int MESSAGE_IS_SEEN = 1;
    private static final String LOCATION_SERVICE = null;

    LocationManager locationManager; 
    Geocoder geocoder; 

     double longitude,latitude;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent m=new Intent(context, ReceivelocationActivity.class);    
          PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, m, 0); 
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = ""; 
        String str2="";
        String str3="";
        String autoReplyToken = "Request_Accepted";
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                str2=msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
             str3=msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";        
            }
            //---display the new SMS message---
            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          //  int number=Integer.parseInt(str2);



            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            boolean isAutoReply = str3.startsWith(autoReplyToken);


            locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE); 

            geocoder = new Geocoder(this); 

            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


            if (location != null) {
              Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
               this.onLocationChanged(location); 

              }


            String msg = Double.toString(latitude) + " " +Double.toString(longitude) ; 
            if (!isAutoReply) {
                String autoReplyText = autoReplyToken + msg;
                sms.sendTextMessage(str2, null, autoReplyText, pi, null);
            }


         //   sms.sendTextMessage(str2, null, "Whats up", pi, null);

        }                 
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


          latitude=location.getLatitude();
       longitude=location.getLongitude();


    }

    private void putSmsToDatabase( ContentResolver contentResolver, SmsMessage sms )
    {
        // Create SMS row
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put( ADDRESS, sms.getOriginatingAddress() );
        values.put( DATE, sms.getTimestampMillis() );
        values.put( READ, MESSAGE_IS_NOT_READ );
        values.put( STATUS, sms.getStatus() );
        values.put( TYPE, MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX );
        values.put( SEEN, MESSAGE_IS_NOT_SEEN );


        // Push row into the SMS table
        contentResolver.insert( Uri.parse( SMS_URI ), values );
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me where am I doing wrong?

pastebin.com/53ZJH3iN  this is the file which reply back to a sms received from user 1 . Instead of sending user 2's location it is sending same location obtained from user 1 back to him.(Here location refers to longitude and latitude). Please help me.I'm breaking my head on this

Comment: Seems you accidentally the code.

Comment: In the future, please just include your code instead of using a pastebin.

Comment: @BrendanLong : Actually formatting is not known to me while posting the code so I post it on pastebin and give that link.

Comment: Guys please help me.I'm really struggling with this one.There are many experience people out there.Please come to my help!!!!

Comment: @code_hacker - I suspect no one is answering because this question is too hard. Generally people focus on things where they can look at a couple lines of code and figure out what's wrong, but you posted over a hundred lines of code. My suggestions: (1) Try to trim your code down to the smallest example that shows your problem and (2) discuss things you've considered and what you think the problem might be (and which part of code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well one problem you have is at line 102:

```
String msg = Double.toString(latitude) + " " +Double.toString(longitude) ;
```

You haven't updated latitude and longitude to reflect your current position. Add this code right before that line:

```
latitude = location.getLatitude();
longitude = location.getLongitude();
```

See what happens once that is fixed.

Comment: I did this but still same problem.Any other idea? I have not used updatefunction() is that causing error? Give some idea please.

Comment: sorry, if that doesn't fix it I'm not sure why it still isn't working. I'll take another look at it though in a bit.