# Difficulty in replying back(location of second user) to a first user's message ?

Tags: java, android, gps, sms, location

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difficulty in sending location of user 1 to user 2 and user 2's location to user 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933577/difficulty-in-sending-location-of-user-1-to-user-2-and-user-2s-location-to-user)

I have an application in which there are two users.User 1 sends some message containing his location to user 2 and in return user 2 sends a message conatining his location to user 1.I'm abled to send the message from user 1 to user 2 and vice-versa.User 1's message conatins his location as expected in application but user 2's message instead of conating his location,conatins the location of user 1,contrary to what expected by application.Can anyone tell me where I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
public class ReceivelocationActivity extends BroadcastReceiver  {

    private static final String TAG = "LocationActivity";

    private static final String LOCATION_SERVICE = null;

    LocationManager locationManager; 
    Geocoder geocoder; 

     double longitude,latitude;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent m=new Intent(context, ReceivelocationActivity.class);    
          PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, m, 0); 
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = ""; 
        String str2="";
        String str3="";
        String autoReplyToken = "Request_Accepted";
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                str += "SMS from " msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                str2=msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
             str3=msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";        
            }
            //---display the new SMS message---
            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          //  int number=Integer.parseInt(str2);



            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            boolean isAutoReply = str3.startsWith(autoReplyToken);


            locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE); 

            geocoder = new Geocoder(this); 

            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


            if (location != null) {
              Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
               this.onLocationChanged(location); 

              }


            String msg = Double.toString(latitude) + " " +Double.toString(longitude) ; 
            if (!isAutoReply) {
                String autoReplyText = autoReplyToken + msg;
                sms.sendTextMessage(str2, null, autoReplyText, pi, null);
            }


         //   sms.sendTextMessage(str2, null, "Whats up", pi, null);

        }                 
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


          latitude=location.getLatitude();
       longitude=location.getLongitude();


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could the problem be that `getLastKnownLocation()` can return null if it doesn't know a good location and emulator returns null too if location is not specified. If you wan't the current position you have to prepared to wait and register a listener:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS, 20000, 1, yourLocationListener);
```

Comment: It is still not working. Any other suggestion ? After I made the changes as suggested by you it will look like :    Here is the link: http://pastebin.com/XU9JTuiZ

Comment: If I saw correctly you send the SMS before waiting for the location. You should probably send the reply only after the listener is called (inside the onLocationChanged), before that you probably don't have the location.

Comment: Can you explain where I'm doing by pointing out the lines which needs to be rearranged because I think that I'm sending message only after calling locationupdate(),correct me if I'm wrong?